# Converting from PSD to PNG in asp.NET?

Tags: asp.net, png, psd

is there any software I can use that allows me to programmatacilly convert a PSD into a PNG in my asp.NET web application? Where transparenct and quality are preserved.

Comment: I'd be surprised if that was possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Photoshop Scripting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html) to automate tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with any libraries personally (I'm sure one must exist capable of this), but I'm curious if between http://psdplugin.codeplex.com/ and possibly the Paint.net code base if you could make one yourself.